# Angular css assets url not pointing to the right directory in ng serve

Tags: angular, assets

I have a css `url()` call in my styles.css file:

```
  background: url(/assets/img/banner/banner-bg.png);
```

When I run `ng serve --open` the file isn't found and I get

```
GET http://localhost:4200/img/banner/hero-banner.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Notice that the `assets` part is missing from the GET request but it is there when I inspect the browser's CSS:

```
    background: url(/assets/img/banner/banner-bg.png);
```

If I try other invalid paths, for example prepending a second `/assets` it throws a `CssSyntaxError: .. Can't resolve <url>` during compilation, so I at least know Angular can find the file. I have several other Angular projects where similar links work. This one is freshly generated by `ng new`. Any ideas?

Comment: is your assets folder declared on algular.json?

Comment: Yes, `"assets": [ "src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],`

Comment: I just created a sample here, and it works fine, I have my jpg file under assets, and added a div on the html, copied your css line.. [check this out](https://imgur.com/0XNRgX5)

Comment: I had an src attribute on an img tag point to the same file without the `/assets` in front. Thanks for the help

Comment: it's harder to help when we don't have the full code, it's always good to provide a minimal working example :)